# React Native passing params in route getting undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, amazon-cognito, stack-navigator

I am trying to send  param from screen A to screen B like this:

this is what I am trying so far:

```
   await Auth.signIn(email, password)
    .then((user) => {
      navigation.navigate('SingInConfirm', {user: user});
    })
```

And on my screen B, I want to recibe user params like this..

```
const SingInConfirmation = ({ route, signIn: signInCb  }) => {
const { user } = route.params;
```

But I am getting this error: `TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'route.params')`

and this is my StackNavigator

```
const AuthStack = createStackNavigator();
const AuthModalStack = createStackNavigator();

const AuthNavigator = ({ signIn }) => (
  <AuthModalStack.Navigator mode="modal" headerMode="none">
    <AuthModalStack.Screen name="AuthPages">
      {() => (
        <AuthStack.Navigator>
          <AuthStack.Screen name="SignIn" component={SignInScreen} />
        </AuthStack.Navigator>
      )}
    </AuthModalStack.Screen>
    <AuthModalStack.Screen name="SingInConfirm">
            {({ navigation }) => <SingInConformation signIn={signIn} navigation={navigation} />}
    </AuthModalStack.Screen>
  </AuthModalStack.Navigator>
);

export default AuthNavigator;
```

Why I can't recibe route params on my screen B?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SingInConformation` component doesn't receive `route` in this line as a prop, you need to provide it, change this line from :

```
{({ navigation }) => <SingInConformation signIn={signIn} navigation={navigation} />}
```

To this:

```
{({ route, navigation }) => <SingInConformation signIn={signIn} navigation={navigation} route={route} />}
```